# How do I make a class to dynamic check different objects variable?

Tags: java

I'm new to Java, and i'm trying to create an automatic working shift schedule.

I want the code to mix four different employees to handle a morning shift and afternoon shift every work day.
I have made some code that just pick a random employee into a shift:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class CreateNewShift {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        int startWeek = 30; //Which week would start from?
        int endWeek = 32; //which week will you end on?
        generateShift(startWeek, endWeek);

    }

    private static void generateShift(int startWeek, int endWeek) {

        String Employees[] = {"Employee1", "Employee2", "Employee3", "Employee4"};
        String morningShift;
        String afternoonShift;

      for (int x = 0; x <= (endWeek - startWeek); x++) { //This is counting the number of weeks
         System.out.println("\nWeek: " + (startWeek+x));

      for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {   //this is finding the next working shift day
          morningShift = p.chooseRandomEmployee(Employees);
          afternoonShift = p.chooseRandomEmployee(Employees);
          if (i == 1) {
            System.out.println("Mon: " + morningShift + " + " + afternoonShift);
          }
          else if (i == 2) {
            System.out.println("Tue: " + morningShift + " + " + afternoonShift);
          }
          else if (i == 3) {
             System.out.println("Wed: " + morningShift + " + " + afternoonShift);
          }
          else if (i == 4) {
            System.out.println("Thu: " + morningShift + " + " + afternoonShift);
          }
          else {
            System.out.println("Fri: " + morningShift + " + " + afternoonShift);
          }
        }
      }
    }



public class Employee {
  public String chooseRandomEmployee(String[] Employees) {
        Random r = new Random();
        int randomNumber = r.nextInt(Employees.length);
        return Employees[randomNumber];
  }
}
```

However, I now want the code to handle more restictions.
So i'm currently trying to add the option for the employees to choose some specific days that they dont want to have a shift. I have done this by adding this code to the Employee class:

```
public class Employee {
  boolean monShift = true;
  boolean tueShift = true;
  boolean wedShift = true;
  boolean thuShift = true;
  boolean friShift = true;

  public String chooseRandomEmployee(String[] Employees) {
        Random r = new Random();
        int randomNumber = r.nextInt(Employees.length);
        return Employees[randomNumber];
  }
}
```

And then i had tried to create new objects in my main class:

```
private static void generateShift(int startWeek, int endWeek) {
        Employee Employee1 = new Employee("Employee1");
        Employee Employee2 = new Employee("Employee2");
        Employee Employee3 = new Employee("Employee3");
        Employee Employee4 = new Employee("Employee4");
        String Employees[] = {"Employee1", "Employee2", "Employee3", "Employee4"};
        String morningShift;
        String afternoonShift;
        ....
```

Quetions:

How can I improve my code in the Employee class to do a check if the random chosen employee have

```
monShift = true;
```

I have tried something like this, but i know it will not work, (and does not work either):

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Employee {
    public String chooseRandomEmployee(String[] Employees) {
        Random r = new Random();
        int randomNumber = r.nextInt(Employees.length);
        **if (("Employee" + randomNumber).monShift == false) {**
           // Go back and try find a new random employee
        }
        else {
          return Employees[randomNumber];
        }
    }
}
```

So i need a way to make my code dynamic to know which object (employee) it has to check if they are available that specific day or not.

Feel free to ask for a deepening if my question is not clear.

Since this i my first question on this forum, I also appriciate feedback if my question and thoughts are too long, or any other comments.

Comment: It looks like you already know the solution: you should be using `Employees[randomNumber]` instead of `"Employee" + randomNumber`.  What else do you need?

Comment: Hi Louis.
```
If (Employees[randomNumber].monShift == false) {
```
Is not a valid function. I would need to choose:
```
if (Employee1.monShift == false) {
}
```
But I want it to choose it dynamically and not just hardcode it.

Comment: What do you mean that it's not a valid function?  There is no possible way to choose something "dynamically" as you describe.  You must use an array or some other data structure.

Comment: How do i create a array structure? Or in another way. If i create a array like this:

Employee[] Employees = new Employee[2];
  
Employees[0] = new Employee("Employee1");
Employees[1] = new Employee("Employee2");

How do i pass this array toanother class where it can do the validatation if Employee[1].monShift is true or false?
I have tried this:
Employee.chooseRandomEmployee(Employees[]);

But it does not seem to work.

Comment: chooseRandomEmployee should be static, and you should write `chooseRandomEmployee(Employees)` without the [].

Answer (score -1):

I dont think that putting the chooseRandomEmployee() function inside the Employee object is a good idea beacuse is not a part of the employee, is not an "action" of it. I think you shiudl put it outside but I want to respect your decision so shoudl check the [do while loop](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-do-while-loop).

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Employee {
    public String chooseRandomEmployee(String[] Employees) {

        int randomNumber;

        do {

        //Generate a new random number
        Random r = new Random();
        randomNumber = r.nextInt(Employees.length);     
   
        //The line under is the same that saying "If monSift == false return to 
        //the beginning and start again generating a new number"
        } while ("Employee" + randomNumber).monShift == false);

        return Employees[randomNumber];
       
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Juan
Thank you for your suggestion.
I think your right about doing a seperate class for this randomGenerator. I will probably change this.

However, the line: 
````
("Employee" + randomNumber).monShift == false)
```
is not a valid function. I need a way to tell Java that i'm giving it the object called Employee1.monShift (which is a valid function). But how do i do that if i want to do it inside a loop? (Employee + i) was just my way of telling what i want. But i know it does not work.

Comment: @Jesper.Ba I think the best way is to put the function outside the object. Also instead of making a array of string make and array of object that contains the Emplyees and pass it to the function as a parameter and so you can use it inside to iterate through the array to check with employee has the condition.

Comment: How do i create a array of objects?
Like this?

        Employee Employee[] = new Employee[4];
        Employee[1] = new Employee();

Or how does it works?

Comment: @Jesper.Ba     Something like this should work  
      Employee[] employeeArray = new Employee[2] ;
     //create & initialize actual employee objects using constructor
     employeeArray[0] = new Employee();
     employeeArray[1] = new Employee();

Comment: I'm still not able to make it work. I can create new employees in this employeeArray. but i'm not able to use this is a condition formula: if (Employee[randomNumber].monShift == false) {

This line does not catch the .monShift
It is just telling me that monShift does not exist which it does.

Comment: @Jesper.Ba dont know exactly what is producing the errorbut try accesing an object varible through the getters. See this https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_encapsulation.asp , is a function inside the object that return a varible